# procurar e substituir string javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

Tenho a seguinte sintaxe:

```
        var json_pessoa = JSON.stringify(json_pessoa["pessoa"]); // o valor do json_pessoa é "{"razao_social":"asd","nome_fantasia":"asd","rg_insc_estadual":"asd"}" , ele já é iniciado com as aspas
        var json_teste1 = '"{"usuario":"';
        var json = frase.replace(json_pessoa.substring(1, 1), json_teste1);
```

o objetivo é substituir o primeiro caractere que é uma aspas duplas (") pela variavel json_teste1, porém ele da erro na depuração e nem sequer informa o tipo de erro.

o string que eu espero de retorno é:

```
{"usuario":{"razao_social":"asd","nome_fantasia":"asd","rg_insc_estadual":"asd"}}
```

Comment: Tem como por na pergunta o retorno esperado?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado , coloquei na pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo exemplo que mostras não precisas de juntar strings dessa maneira. Simplesmente ter um objeto e fazer um json dele. Ou seja:

```js
var pessoa = '{"razao_social":"asd","nome_fantasia":"asd","rg_insc_estadual":"asd"}'
var objeto = {
  usuario: JSON.parse(pessoa)
};
var resultado = JSON.stringify(objeto);
console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: era isso que eu precisava, por falta de conhecimento tava tentando fazer uma gambiarra usando o replace, mais uma vez obrigado!